# Check browser size on resize with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having to style the page differently depending on the browser size with jQuery. However, when the user makes the page larger, we're stuck with the jQuery that was supposed to be for smaller screens.

**I cannot use media queries, because some elements are styled with `.width()`.**

What's the best way to ask on resize, `if the browser is over or under a certain size` — and are there many performance issues with calling on resize (assuming it gets called multiple times a second?)

Answer (score 1):

You can look for the resize event like so and get the width and height

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(window).height();
});
```

taken from here https://api.jquery.com/resize/

As to your question about performance this depends on the browser. Some wait for the resizing to stop and others give a running feed as the change happens.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can get the width and height

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(window).height();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against just hooking on to the window resize event, instead throttle/debounce the resize event to avoid performance issues.

## "Debouncing" explained:

> Throttling is the reduction in rate of a repeating event. Throttling
>   is good for reducing mousemove events to a lesser, manageable rate,
>   for instance.
>
> Debouncing is quite more precise. Debouncing ensures that exactly one
>   signal is sent for an event that may be happening several times — or
>   even several hundreds of times over an extended period. As long as the
>   events are occurring fast enough to happen at least once in every
>   detection period, the signal will not be sent!

<sup>Source: http://unscriptable.com/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/</sup>

## Code:

```
(function($,sr){

  // debouncing function from John Hann
  // http://unscriptable.com/index.php/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/
  var debounce = function (func, threshold, execAsap) {
      var timeout;

      return function debounced () {
          var obj = this, args = arguments;
          function delayed () {
              if (!execAsap)
                  func.apply(obj, args);
              timeout = null;
          };

          if (timeout)
              clearTimeout(timeout);
          else if (execAsap)
              func.apply(obj, args);

          timeout = setTimeout(delayed, threshold || 100);
      };
  }
  // smartresize 
  jQuery.fn[sr] = function(fn){  return fn ? this.bind('resize', debounce(fn)) : this.trigger(sr); };

})(jQuery,'smartresize');


// usage:
$(window).smartresize(function(){
  // code that takes it easy...
});
```

<sup>Code (shamelessly) taken from: http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/</sup>

[See example codepen](http://codepen.io/andyunleash/pen/IKFen) (taken from comments in above linked/blog article)

Comment: That sounds like it could be best. Could give me an example, or linked to a source?

Comment: I don't understand why actually is better to use the timer instead the resize method. Something to do with performance?